# Java 8 - Group by a List, sort and display the total count of it

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am just playing with the **groupingBy** in `Java8` using **streams**. I am unable to sort the fruits according to the name of the fruite, I also wanted to sort based on the name of fruites for (// 1.1== >Group by a List and display the total count of it)

```
public class StreamCollectorsGroupingByDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList("apple", "apple", "banana", "apple", "orange", "banana", "papaya");

        // 1.1== >Group by a List and display the total count of it
        Map<String, Long> result = items.stream()
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println("RESULT : "+result);

        // 1.2 Add sorting
        Map<String, Long> finalMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        result.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long> comparingByValue()
            .reversed())
            .forEachOrdered(e -> finalMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
        System.out.println("FINAL RESULT : "+finalMap);
    }
}
```

**The output is:**

```
RESULT : {papaya=1, orange=1, banana=2, apple=3}
FINAL RESULT : {apple=3, banana=2, papaya=1, orange=1}
```

I want the output like below

```
RESULT : {apple=3,banana=2, orange=1,papaya=1}
```

Comment: you asked for the `Map` there so your sorting is really meaningless...

Comment: well, from your current output I already see RESULT is correct, modulo its order, and FINAL RESULT actually gives the order you want already. I am not sure what prevents you from turning FINAL RESULT to RESULT.

Comment: You are using `comparingByValue().reversed()` instead of `comparingByValue()`, so your final result is actually the reverse order of the counts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `Supplier<Map>` that will create `LinkedHashMap` for you using [this version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) of overloaded methods `groupingBy`:

```
Map<String, Long> result = items.stream()
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println("RESULT : "+result);
```

Output now is:

```
RESULT : {apple=3, banana=2, orange=1, papaya=1}
FINAL RESULT : {apple=3, banana=2, orange=1, papaya=1}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can either sort the stream and then add entries to a `LinkedHashMap`, or don't sort the stream at all and add entries to a `TreeMap`, so that sorting is done when inserting to the tree.

`LinkedHashMap` version:

```
Map<String, Long> result = items.stream()
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), 
        LinkedHashMap::new, 
        Collectors.counting()));
```

`TreeMap` version:

```
Map<String, Long> result = items.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), 
        TreeMap::new, 
        Collectors.counting()));
```

You might also want to use a non-stream version:

```
Map<String, Long> result = new TreeMap<>();
items.forEach(e -> result.merge(e, 1L, Long::sum));
```

Which uses [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method and is both shorter and more performant.

Comment: I also prefer the `TreeMap` version since it does not need to sort the whole dataset upfront. However the difference in performance of the non-stream version is probably negligible.